# I archived an email by mistake, can I retrieve it?

Tags: gmail

I archived an email by mistake, is there a way to retrieve it?

Comment: Sure, archive is not deleted. Check "[all mail](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all)" or "done"

Comment: If you're asking about Gmail, the answers on [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1168/354) should be helpful.

Comment: If you're talking about 'inbox' then just find the email in 'all mail' or 'done' as suggested, but click on the tick again, will bring it back to the inbox.

Answer (score 2):

When you archive an email, it gets moved from your inbox to a label called "**All Mail**" and isn't deleted. Open the message, and choose the **Move to Inbox** option to unarchive it.

If someone replies to a message you've archived, the message will come back to your inbox.

Comment: Actually all mail has the label "all mail"; archived items have the "inbox" label removed.

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to choose _Move to Inbox_.

Comment: Even mail that was never archived has the all mail label.